# Admin account goes back to login screen

Tags: login, lightdm

I'm looking for a bit of help before I go insane. For some reason, I can't log into my admin account anymore. I keep getting kicked back to the login screen.  I have done the following:

1. Renamed, re-chowned, removed both `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` files
2. Looked in `.xsession-errors`, and found nothing helpful
3. Verified that my `/etc/x11/default-display-manager` is `/usr/sbin/lightdm`
4. Done a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session`
5. Created a new user and tried logging in as that user...that is successful, so I doubt that it is video drivers

And of course have done a ton of searches without good result.

At best, I have been able to get to where I can log in as my admin user and get about 15 seconds in the environment before getting kicked back to the login screen.

There has to be a fix that works....any other solutions?